# Select a css class from an item value

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, razor-pages

In a cshtml page I'm able to select a class in function of a database value. Example:

```
<div class="alert @item.State" role="alert">@item.State</div>
```

"State" is an enum of my table defined as follow:

```
public enum States
{
    Ready,
    Setup,
    Pause,
    Error,
    Maintenance,
    Emergency,
    Disconnected
}
```

the Razor syntax above will add a class to my alert in function of the item value. Good!

But now I need to "translate" this class to Bootstrap's one. Example:

```
Ready: alert-primary 
Pause or Disconnected: alert-secondary
Error: alert-danger
etc...
```

I'm able to this manually with Razor, but I wonder if there's a convenient way to this directly in css, something like (metacode):

```
.Ready {
    return alert-primary
}

.Pause, .Disconnect {
    return alert-secondary
}
```

Comment: Hello, do you use a preprocessor, like sass or less ?

Comment: Currently, I don't.

Comment: With sass you could extend class. It works just like OOP inheritance

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an array of strings which will contain the class names:

```
string[] ClassList = new string[]
{
    "ReadyClass", "SetupClass", "PauseClass", "ErrorClass", "MaintenanceClass", "EmergencyClass", "DisconnectedClass"
};
```

Now you can display the equivalent class name using the following line

```
@ClassList[(int)item.State]
```

I did not test it but it should work.

Comment: This is indeed a working solution, though is in the group I generally described as "do manually with Razor".